# Working with Vizceral and Elastic Search

Tags: netflix

I am trying to integrate Vizceral with the packet beat data collect from my cluster. I started with the Vizceral example but I am not able to get how to convert the ELK response to the format Vizceral understand. Is there a format converter I can use or a sample format in which I can write a converter and feed it to Vizceral.

Comment: I found https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/cinnamon/current/visualizations/vizceral.html

I will check it and if it is good for integrating, I will answer here again.